# Jquery alert box if user log in/authentication fails using passportjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, passport.js, passport-local

I am currently trying to get an jQuery alert box to pop when a user fails to authenticate using passport for not entering the right username and password in my node/express application.

I do have an alert box pop when this happens, but it literally shows for about 0.5 seconds, then vanishes again before you can read it. But I need it to stay until the user interacts with it accordingly and I am unsure of why it wont.

Reference to what it looks like am what am using found [here](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message).

I have attempted to use connect- flash but couldn't get it to work at all with all the examples I found. Is there any way for me just to have the alert box stay instead of appear and then instantly just vanish.

**Server Side Code**

```
//Global vars
var ari = require('ari-client');
var util = require('util');
var error;
var state;
var response;
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'test',
    password : '',
    database : 'test'
  });
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var passport = require('passport');
var passportLocal = require('passport-local');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');

server = require('http').createServer(app),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

  server.listen(3010, function () {
    console.log('listening on *:3010');
  });

  //All express middleware located here.
  //Access to local folder called public, enables the usage of local path files for CSS/JS/Images etc.
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
  app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console
  app.use(cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
  app.use(flash());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
      extended : false
    }));
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.use(session({
      secret : 'testersecret',
      name: 'Test-cookie',
      resave : false,
      saveUninitialized : false,
      cookie : {
        maxAge : 3600000
      } // 1 Hour
    })); // session secret
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());

  //Use passport and local strategy, outcome for success or failure is then dependent on if the users details that they entered matched up with the values in the database.
  passport.use(new passportLocal.Strategy(function (username, password, done) {
      //SQL Query to run. where the values passed are paired which and compared in the DB table.
      connection.query({
        sql : 'SELECT * from `userman_users` WHERE `username`= ?AND`password` = sha1(?)',
        timeout : 40000, // 40s
        values : [username, password]
      }, function (err, results, rows) {
        if (results.length > 0) {
          response = "Success";
          console.log(results);
        } else {
          console.log('Error while performing Query.');
          console.log(error);
          response = "Failed";
        }
        if (response === "Success") {
          done(null, {
            id : username
          });
        } else if (response === "Failed") {
          error = ("Incorrect username or password");
          Error();
          done(null, null);
        }
      });

    }));

  //Serialize user information
  passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  //Deserialize User information
  passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    done(null, {
      id : id
    });
  });

  //Gets the login route and renders the page.
  app.get('/', redirectToIndexIfLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
    res.render('login');
  });

  //The index page, isLoggedIn function always called to check to see if user is authenticated or in a session, if they are they can access the index route, if they are not they will be redirected to the login route instead.
  app.get('/index', checkLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
      isAuthenticated : req.isAuthenticated(),
      user : req.user
    });
  });

  //This is where the users log in details are posted to, if they are successfull then redirect to index otherwise keep them on the login route.
  app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
      successRedirect : '/index',
      failureRedirect : '/',
      failureFlash : 'Invalid username or password.'
    }));

  //When logout is clicked  it gets the user, logs them out and deletes the session, session cookie included then redirects the user back to the login route.
  app.get('/logOut', function (req, res) {
    req.logOut();
    req.session.destroy();
    res.redirect('/')
  });

  //Check to see if logged in, if so carry on otherwise go back to login.
  function checkLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

    // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on to the next middleware stack.
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
      return next();

    // if they aren't redirect them to the index page
    res.redirect('/');
  }

  // If user authenticated then redirect to index, than arry on to the next middleware stack.
  function redirectToIndexIfLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
      res.redirect('/index');

    return next();
  }

  /*Server side listeners for all the ARI functionality from the client side E.G Kick/Mute,
  This handles all real time updating/maintains proper state even if page refreshed.*/
  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  });

  //Updates the web page, used to update webpage in real time, and call channel dump function.
  //Used for error handling, emits error message to the server side to be displayed.
  function Error() {
    io.sockets.emit("error", error);
    error = '';
  }
```

**Client Side Code**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    //Global Varibles
    var socket = io.connect();

    //Handles all error messages for the stasis application being passed from the server side functions.
    socket.on("error", function (err) {
        $("<div title='Error Message'>" + err + "</div>").dialog({
            modal : true,
            buttons : {
                Ok : function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Form**

```
    <div class="container">

        <form action="/login" id="form_reset" method="post" class="form-signin">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
            <label for="inputUser" class="sr-only">Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="inputUser" name ="username" class="form-control username" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
                <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control password" placeholder="Password" required>
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block clear" type="submit">Sign in</button>
                </form>

            </div>
```

I am not too great with passport as I have only recently started using it, so sorry if its a simple question.....I just need the jQuery alert box to stay!

Any advice or guidance would help.

Comment: all the nodejs code seems to be irrelevant. Where is your client code?

Comment: @Gavriel Added the client code which emits the error message to the web page, that is what your asking for I presume.

Comment: yes, and the code that validates, submits the form? What happens after the 1/2 second? Does your page refresh?

Comment: @Gavriel The form is above and it posts the the information to  "app.post('/login', passport.authenticate" I believe the issue is a refresh yes causing the dialogue box to vanish.

Comment: Still important parts of the client code are missing. If you look at this form + client code, then it's simple: You have a simple html form that posts the username + password to the server. The code snipplet with your modal dialog is not related to the form at all. But you say it's shown for 1/2 second, so there must be some other missing code that causes it to show up, but doesn't stop the refresh when the password is incorrect

Comment: @Gavriel What important parts? The rest of the client code has nothing to do with the login page I can post it all if you want, the dialogue box works fine on the following page as expected. So it seems to be a refresh when after the details that are passed but the box gets displayed before the refresh causing it.

Comment: There has to be some more, otherwise your dialog wouldn't even show up for 1/2 sec

Comment: @Gavriel In terms of client side, no there is nothing and I just tested it and the dialogue box still shows up with the server-side code inserted into the question. The only things I could add is the rest if my socket.io stuff which doesn't really have any relevance to the question or my global vars etc. EDITl I have updated the code, and the same thing happens and it works accordingly, the only other thing I could add is the HTML for the login. So am unsure of what you think is missing, because it works & acts accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100977/discussion-between-gavriel-and-studento919).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

failureFlash means it's flashing the message, but I don't see how can you tell for how long it should be kept.

Maybe you should redirect to /error#Incorrect Password, and display the hash (what is after #) in the dialog.